# Porque se cambia el valor del atributo translate a "yes", cuando lo agrego desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, traducción

Hola el problema es que tengo un span con la propiedad `contentEditable="true"` para que el usuario pueda escribir en el, pero este se agrega desde javascript. y me gustaría omitirlo al momento de que el navegador traduzca la pagina.

Trate lo siguiente pero no me funciona

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>HOla Mundo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
}
span{
    background: #333770;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

index.js

```
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.contentEditable = "true";
span.translate = "no";

document.body.appendChild(span)
```

Por alguna razon la propiedad `translate ="no"` se cambia a `"yes"` cuando se agrega al DOM. ¿como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero**, el atributo [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/translate) no es completamente estándar (es parte de la especificación propuesta HTML 5.1 entiendo) por lo que aunque todos los browsers la soporten, su implementación puede variar.

**Segundo**, un [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) tiene propiedades (e.g. `id`, `className`) y atributos. Los atributos están agrupados dentro de la propiedad `attributes`. En particular,  `translate` **no es una propiedad sino un atributo**. Cuando el browser se encuentra con el tag

```
 <span id="mi_elemento" translate="no">hello</span>
```

Lo incorpora al DOM con una *propiedad* **attributes** que a su vez contiene `translate` y cuyo valor es `false`. Muy burdamente

- Element

  - tagName: `SPAN`
  - id: `mi_elemento`
  - attributes  <---- por si a alguien le interesa este es un objeto de tipo [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap)

    - translate: `false`

El hecho de que `"no"` se interprete como `false` es una simple convención. De [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/translate):

> Cadena vacía y "yes", que indica que el elemento debe de ser traducido cuando la página es localizada. "no", que indica que el elemento no debe de ser traducido.

Sin esa convención, para ilustrarlo, no tendría sentido que

```
<span translate></span>
```

Se parseara como `true`, cuando en JS puro en el mejor de los casos sería `undefined`.

En tu caso, puedes declarar `span.translate = false` en vez de `span.translate = "no"`, o bien usar `span.setAttribute('translate', 'no');` (me parece que lo segundo es más future-proof).

```js
function createSpanWithId(id) {
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.id = id;
  return span;
}

let  conString = createSpanWithId('conString'),
     conBoolean = createSpanWithId('conBoolean'),
     conSetAttributeNo = createSpanWithId('conSetAttributeNo');

conString.translate = 'no'; 
// se interpretó como TRUE
console.log(conString, conString.translate);

conBoolean.translate = false;
console.log(conBoolean, conBoolean.translate);

conSetAttributeNo.setAttribute('translate', 'no');
console.log(conSetAttributeNo, conSetAttributeNo.translate);
```

## Bonus Track

Como con cualquier objeto JS, el objeto devuelto por `document.createElement` permite que le asignes propiedades extra, pero aquellas sin sentido semántico no tienen influencia en la manera como se renderiza el DOM.  Esto implica que

```
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.atributoCustom = "valorCustom";
span.id = "mi_elemento";
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

No genera en el DOM una entrada con "atributoCustom" dentro de "attributes". PEEERO, `span.atributoCustom` así como `document.getElementById('mi_elemento').atributoCustom` sí devuelve `valorCustom` y esto es algo bueno porque significa que puedes extender el elemento. Se recomienda eso sí usar un namespace para no pasar a llevar nada.

En en el flujo HTML -> DOM un atributo arbitrario en cambio sí termina dentro de attributes y hay que leerlo con `span.getAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Por una parte la manera en que lo estás haciendo no es la correcta:
Edita la linea:

```
span.translate = "no";
```

y añade lo siguiente:

```
span.setAttribute("translate","no");
```

Pero este atributo no lo soportan los navegadores Chrome, Edge, Zafari, Mozilla ni Opera.
Lo correcto añadir una clase "notranslate" con esto el navegador sabe por defecto que ese elemento no será traducido:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="translate">Will be translated</p>
    <p class="notranslate">Will not be translated</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No tenia idea que no lo soportaba. alguna idea para no traducir un texto?.